# SPARQL: Querying for all instances of a URI

Tags: sparql, rdf

I'm trying to query for all instances of a specific URI in an RDF database. The URI could be in either the 'subject', 'predicate', 'object', or 'named graph' position of all quads. We are not worried about there being multiple instances of the URI in a single quad.

Comment: I suppose URIs are "instantiated" by quads, i. e. you need all ?g ?s ?p ?o with your URI in any position? Then try to adopt query from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47241152/7879193

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ask if SPARQL resource exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225585/ask-if-sparql-resource-exists)